# Trying to merge files after removing duplicate content

Tags: python, linux, algorithm, bash

Here is my problem.

I have n files and they all have overlapping and common text in them. I want to create a file using these n files such that the new file only contains unique lines in it that exist across all of the n files.

I am looking for a bash command, python api that can do it for me. If there is an algorithm I can also attempt to code it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *order* of the lines is not important, you could do this:

```
sort -u file1 file2 ...
```

This will (a) sort all the lines in all the files, and then (b) remove duplicates.  This will give you the lines that are unique among all the files.

Answer (score 2):

For testing common data you can use `comm`:

```
DESCRIPTION
     The comm utility reads file1 and file2, which should be sorted lexically, 
and produces three text columns as output: lines only in file1; lines only in 
file2; and lines in both files.
```

Another useful tool would be `merge`:

```
DESCRIPTION
merge  incorporates all changes that lead from file2 to file3 into file1. 
The result ordinarily goes into file1.  merge is useful for combining separate 
changes to an original.
```

`sort` might mess up your order. You can try the following `awk` command. It hasn't been tested so make sure you backup your files. :)

```
awk ' !x[$0]++' big_merged_file
```

This will remove all duplicate lines from your file.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
# ( seq 1 5; seq 3 7; )
1
2
3
4
5
3
4
5
6
7
# ( seq 1 5; seq 3 7; ) | sort -nu
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
# ( seq 1 5; seq 3 7; ) | sort -n | uniq -u
1
2
6
7
# ( seq 1 5; seq 3 7; ) | sort -n | uniq -d
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge everything first, sort then finally remove duplicates

#!/bin/bash
for file in test/*
do
 cat "$file" >> final
done
sort final > final2
uniq final2 final
rm -rf final2